# Do Java access modifiers use permissions from the operating system or is the access controlled by Java itself?

Tags: java, operating-system, access-modifiers

I have found many, many resources about Java access modifiers that explain what they are and how to use them and why to use them and when to use them. But, I have found no discussion on how they work or how much Java depends on the operating system to enforce them and if so, how much the enforcement is dependent on which operating system is used. Possibly, I am using the wrong search terms.

Comment: Basically it's 100% controlled by Java and the JVM, and the OS has nothing to do with it.  There's no hardware intervention (for example) in controlling access to a private field.  It's just the software running on the JVM doesn't let you (directly, you can do it with reflection) read the memory location of that field.

Comment: Could you make that an answer, so I can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's 100% controlled by Java and the JVM, and the OS has nothing to do with it. There's no hardware intervention (for example) in controlling access to a private field. It's just the software running on the JVM doesn't let you (directly, you can do it with reflection) read the memory location of that field.

AFAIK, all Java objects are allocated on the heap which is just ordinary memory that can be read or written.  Some parts of the JVM might actually be protect by the OS -- executable memory for example, or the stack.  But Java is a unified memory system where all memory, all objects and their fields, go in the same OS "bucket" of memory, and that's the heap.

I think this is sometimes called a SISD model -- "single instruction single data," where the "single data" is just the heap.  And yes I'm ignoring the SIMD instructions that Intel has because those instructions are relatively rare.

Comment: That is precisely the amount of information I needed. I'm writing some little posts for a friend who is considering learning Java, and I realized I had no idea how it works regarding the permissions beyond use and planning.

Comment: It's a very high level overview.  The hairy details are always up to the implementors (the folks who write the JVM).  If you want more you can look for books with the subject "unix internals" which will give you a lot of info about how OSs allocate and control their memory systems.